# getSqlSession().selectOne() returns null

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I am working on mybatis. I am trying to execute below query to get result.

```
<select id="getMaxSeqNumFromTrans" parameterType="com.abc.ContributionsRequestParamDto" resultType="java.lang.Integer" >
    SELECT MAX(SEQ_NMBR) MAXNUMBER FROM DB2.A_PDC_TRNS WHERE TOKEN_ID = #{tokenID} AND RSLT_TYP = 10
```

In java code I am using this code to run above query-

```
Integer maxSeqNumber = getSqlSession().selectOne("getMaxSeqNumFromTrans", contributionsParam);
```

But this code returns null to me. I don't know what is going wrong here. Did I miss something?

Comment: try to use `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SEQ_NMBR), 0) MAXNUMBER ...`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much !

Comment: this is nice to hear this, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is with your query. MAX would give you null if no rows were found for your where clause.

Have you tried running your query manually on the server through some tool?

Comment: Yes. you are right. I have changed my query as suggested by @YCF_L

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that :)